# AppStore Promtional Artwork Approved - Not Used

Tags: ios-appstore, development, app-store-connect

8 days ago, Apple emailed me and asked me to provide promotional artwork for an iOS App which I published on March 7. They needed me to upload promotional artwork for a possible feature on the App Store. I submitted it and it was approved on March 17.

As you may know, Apple refreshes the App Store every Thursday at about 12:00 Pacific Time. Unfortunately, my app was not featured.

So I have a few questions about this:
1. Will my app ever be featured (the artwork request was approved and still shows up in iTC)?
2. When will it show up (if it does)?
3. Why wouldn't it be featured after Apple requested artwork?

Comment: I'm interested in knowing if your app was featured after you posted this message ?
I'm exactly in the same situation: promo artwork requested and approved about 3 days ago, and still nothing featured on the app store.
Thanks for sharing your experience.
J

Comment: @jerome Still nothing, months later... And I doubt they will feature it without a major update (just take a look at the release dates of featured apps - it's very close to the Thursday they were featured). I tried to contact Apple twice with no response. Just remember that to even be considered for a feature your app has to be stunning (there's just something that Apple thought needed to be changed / improved. For example: localization, pricing, screenshots?). What's your app? I'll take a look at it! :)